# "He is eating for a long time"

Tags: grammar

He is eating.

> He is eating for a long time.

How do I say he takes a long time to eat lunch? Would it sound awkward?

Comment: Anecdotally, and idiomatically, I routinely hear "he took a long lunch".

Comment: Your own phrasing is fine - *he takes a long time to eat lunch*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good example where you want to use the present perfect progressive tense to say that the action started in the past and is still going on:

> He **has been eating** for a long time.

Other examples:

> He **has been resting** since yesterday.
>
> My son **has been playing** his game all day.

Alternately, use the present perfect to indicate a condition that started in the past and is still valid:

> He **has been at lunch** for a long while.
>
> He **has been tired** for some time.
>
> My son **has been an avid gamer** since he could pick up the controller.